# Magento - Get Category in Homepage if Custom Attribute is Equal to Yes

Tags: php, magento

I have created a custom yes/no attribute in the magento category:

```
$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
$setup->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'in_slider', array(
    'group' => 'General Information',
    'input' => 'select',
    'type' => 'int',
    'source' => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean',
    'label' => 'Nella Slide dei Brand',
    'required' => 0,
    'unique' => 0,
    'sort_order' => 3,
    'user_defined' => 1,
    'global' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
));
```

Now I need to get the category images and names of all the category with that attribute equal to yes and show in homepage. I cannot find any code for do so in the homepage, so I can't understand where to start from.

Ihave tried the following:

```
foreach ($this->getStoreCategories() as $_category): 
    $cur_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId());
    if($cur_category->getinSlider()) : // Check if the featured category is enabled

<h1>Test</h1>
```

But I'm think that I'm pretty far.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this. It should work.

```
<?php 
$_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category');
$_categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories();
if (count($_categories) > 0){
    foreach($_categories as $_category){
        $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId());
           if($_category->getinSlider()) : // Check if the featured category is enabled
               // Your Logic here
               endif;


    }
}
?>
```

Comment: thank you! I have added an h1 for test near '// Your Logic Here', but it just output blank

Comment: @filippo90 do you have attribute in_slider for category right?

Comment: yes, it appear in the category general information tab. I have added it with the code in the question ($setup->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'in_slider', array)

Comment: `foreach($_categories as $_category){
        $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId());
          var_dump($_category);


    }`

Comment: Try this and see result contain your new attribute?

Comment: It throw the following error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/pier/public_html/app/design/frontend/evolve/evolve/template/page/html/brand-slider.phtml on line 16

Comment: Maybe the problem is that I'm not in the category page, but in a phtm file called inside a cms page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128048/discussion-between-kul-and-filippo90).

Answer (score 0):

Please change getinSlider() to  getInSlider() in if condition and then write your logic.

```
<?php 
$_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category');
$_categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories();
if (count($_categories) > 0){
    foreach($_categories as $_category){
        $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId());
           if($_category->getinSlider()) : // Check if the featured category is enabled
               // Your Logic here
               endif;


    }
}
?>
```